# I have linked the Flutter Desktop application to the Firebase database, but I am getting this message

Tags: flutter, windows, firebase

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.
#0      DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform (package:elsafa/firebase_options.dart:30:9)
#1      main (package:elsafa/main.dart:8:37)
#2      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:301:23)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#4      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

[image]

I want to create a desktop application and connect it to a Firebase database

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting states the problem:

> DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.

Please refer to the [FlutterFire CLI documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#using-the-flutterfire-cli):

> **Note**
>
> If you add support for a new platform in your Flutter app (e.g. adding Android when your app previously did not support Android), or if you introduce new Firebase services into your app (e.g. adding `firebase_database`) then you should reconfigure Firebase for your application again via the CLI (`flutterfire configure`).